# Using Managed Preferences to set permissions on a folder

Tags: macos

Does anyone know how to use MCX to set permissions on a folder for a network folder

Comment: You can't; MCX manages preferences, and permissions are not preferences. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am am doing a cache redirect, for Adobe, however atomic writes fail, so I use MCX to move the TemporaryItems folder to the root of the share, however I need to then set the owner and permissions on this folder as its currently inaccsible to the current user.

Comment: as Login hooks are deprecated I guess Ill need a launchdaemon, unless there is another way?
I have no idea how to create a Launchd

Answer (score 2):

nevermind its not needed. I had set the MCX redirection incorrectly.